# String to Array with condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a props in vue like this,

```
props: {
  variant : String
}
```

but I want it to be an array if the value of variant is greater than 1. How can I do it?

Comment: please explain more

Comment: @zhera What do you mean?

Comment: Actually I just want to know how to convert a String to become an Array with condition if the return value is more than 1 @SaeedShamloo

Comment: Could you add an example to your question of what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `computed` to replace it

```
props: {
  variant : String
},
computed: {
  computedVariant() {
    return this.variant.length > 1 ?
      [this.variant] :
      this.variant
  }
}
```

then use the `computedVariant` instead of `variant` in your template

```
<div>{{ computedVariant }}</div>
```